# Scope of a temporary mysql table or specifying that a table is temporary

Tags: mysql, sql

In a set of prepared statements I want to pass the keys found in one prepared statement into a later prepared statement.

I can do this using:

```
PREPARE get_Class_Session FROM
    "CREATE TABLE time_Table_Keys 
             (SELECT time_Table_Key,
                           date,
                           DATE_FORMAT(date, '%W') AS day,
                           slot,
                           class_Session 
                FROM `Time_Table` 
             WHERE (((date >=? && date <= ?) && DAYOFWEEK(date)=? && (slot >=? && slot <=?)) && class_Session ='0')
            )";
```

Followed by:

```
PREPARE update_Time_Table FROM
    "UPDATE Time_Table SET class_Session='8888'
      WHERE time_Table_Key IN ( SELECT time_Table_Key FROM time_Table_Keys)";
```

And lastly:

```
PREPARE drop_Tmp_Table FROM
    "DROP TABLE time_Table_Keys";
```

However:

I really want to use `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` and `DROP TEMPORARY TABLE` but when I attempt to do that the IN clause cannot find the temporary table because of course it doesn't exist when the prepare is parsed.

Is there some way of specifying the scope of a temporary file and or is there someway of telling the prepare that the table in the IN clause is temporary.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing something, but do you even need the temp tables for this particular case?  Would something like this work?

```
UPDATE Time_Table 
SET class_Session='8888'
WHERE 
(
  (
     (date >=? && date <= ?) && 
     DAYOFWEEK(date)=? && 
     (slot >=? && slot <=?)
  ) 
  && class_Session ='0'
)
```

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/03f54/1).

Comment: ok yes totally accept what you are saying there. But this is just one instance and I would still like to understand how a temporary table might be utilised within prepared statements.

Comment: @wickedrunr - please do not simply edit out "Good luck"; these are minor edits and clog the review queue with needless reviews.  Please only edit if you *substantially* improve a question or answer.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables then there should be a way to flag an edit as "minor" (as in Wikipedia), since it makes no sense not to be able to improve a bad post. You can't even fix small grammar errors since edits <10 chars are rejected!

Comment: @Lohoris - there is a "Minor" reject option, and it *was* rejected as minor. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/140011/148949.  Anyways, this is clogging up an answer, so we can continue in chat if you want.